# How to get Brave Browser for any linux distribution

Tags: linux, browser, brave

I have tried installing Brave Browser from their [official page](https://brave.com/linux/#linux). But I keep getting an error an `openPGP key` in this line `echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main"|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list`. Same with Fedora. It's becuase his page doesn't exist itself. What should I do? Also I have tried alternates like Vivaldi but I prefer Brave. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pages seem to exist for me(I am able to open and download the [signing keys](https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg))  via a browser, so I wonder if there's some 'other' issue here. In the longer term - I suspect you might want to see if there's a network or other configuration issue somewhere. That's beyond the scope of this answer.

In *theory* - you should also be able to get [the signing keys here](https://brave.com/signing-keys/), saving them as `/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg` for ubuntu, and following the rest of the instructions. The curl step 'simply' downloads the keyring to the appropriate channel and saves it in the appropriate location

Comment: as an aside, outside the context of this answer, ipv6 is a bit flakey so if you do have ipv6 supported, trying `ping -v4 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg` - which means the ipv4 address is cached, then following instructions as given